# Creating jqplot graph in php page

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, jqplot

Im trying to learn php by doing a little project using apache server.  I have a php page where I want to display a bar chart with jqplot using data i pull from a MySql query.  I already have a query working giving me the data i want.  The problem is i dont know how to implement this into a jqplot graph.  Im guessing i need to make an ajax call but if i can avoid that i would like to.  my php page code so far is here http://snipt.org/oknnl2.
the javascript for the bar chart is here http://snipt.org/oknoi3.
i want the chart to render in div id=chartdiv thats on line 177.  I have to visualize like 6 charts. if i can get some help on doing this one, im sure i can use the same process to build the others.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PHP cannot create the javascript plot and send it downstream to the client, but you don't have to make an actual AJAX call after the page is loaded either. Simple javascript once the page loads will suffice. If you retrieve the data you need at the PHP level, you can then make it available to javascript in the HTML received by the client. The steps to make this happen:

1. First, use PHP to retrieve the data you need from the MySQL database.
2. Then, output the plot data you retrieved using PHP inside a javascript
   code block as part of the HTML that PHP sends to the client.
3. Execute the javascript with the data seeded by PHP on page load.

So, a simplified example:

```
<?php

// Retrieve plot data from mysql
$q = '...';
$r = mysql_query($q);

$plot_row1 = array();
$plot_row2 = array();
$plot_row3 = array();

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($r)) {
    // append values to $plot_row1, $plot_row2 and $plot_row3 arrays
}

$my_page_title = 'My first PHP/JS Combo Foray';

?>

<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/jquery-1.5.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/my_plotter.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<h1><?php echo $my_page_title; ?></h1>

<div id="chartdiv">
    Hold on, javascript is loading the plot ...
</div>

</body>
</html>


<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

    // we're combining the php array elements into a comma separated list
    // so that when the code is output javascript thinks it's an array.
    // if the $plot_row1 = array(1, 2, 3) then we'd get this:
    // 
    // row1 = [1, 2, 3];
    // 
    // if you needed quotes around the imploded php array values (if they
    // are strings where javascript is concerned) you could do this instead:
    // 
    // row1 = ["<?php echo substr(implode('","', $plot_row1), 0, -2); ?>"];

    row1 = [ <?php echo rtrim(implode(',', $plot_row1), ','); ?> ];
    row2 = [ <?php echo rtrim(implode(',', $plot_row2), ','); ?> ];
    row3 = [ <?php echo rtrim(implode(',', $plot_row3), ','); ?> ];

    // call your js function that creates the plot
    showBrittleness(row1,row2,row3);

    // add whatever js code you need to append the plot to $('#chartdiv')
}
</script>
```

**UPDATE**

According to a cursory examination of the [jqplot docs](http://www.jqplot.com/docs/files/usage-txt.html), if you edit line 12 of the javascript you link from this:

```
var plot1 = $.jqplot('chart1', [s1, s2], {
```

To this:

```
var plot1 = $.jqplot('chartdiv', [s1, s2], {
```

Your function should render the plot in the 'chartdiv' id element. It seems the first argument to the $.jqplot function is the element in which to create it ...

Comment: it depends on how the jqplot works ... i was just answering the question (how to merge the javascript with the php functionality) ... i'm not a js expert. i'd recommend looking at the jqplot documentation -- that's what i'd hafta do

Comment: actually, quick update: looking at the jqplot docs it's clear. updating post now.